# Can't wake up computer after sleep - nvidia GTX1060

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, suspend

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with nvidia gtx1060.

I had a problem with resolution, which was only going up to 1024x768, but I fixed it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

Now I have a problem with resuming from sleep on Ubuntu. It's a dual boot, and on Windows I don't have this problem.

When I put the system to sleep and immediately wake up it works fine, but when the computer sleeps for a long time, I can't wake it up.

When I press the button to start the computer, fans start working and the computer starts, but the monitor doesn't have input. I tried to fix it:

```
sudo apt update
```

and

```
Sudo apt upgrade
```

But that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Upgrade your kernel.

This has been a real nightmare for me. I tried everything – messing with the `.conf` file, playing around with `grub`, toggling Nvidia modes... I even gave different Nvidia drivers a shot: 525, 535, 470 – but nothing worked. I kept getting errors (no HDMI connection...) and every time I woke my system from sleep, there was just a black screen staring back at me.

But guess what fixed it? The darn kernel. I updated Ubuntu to the latest 23.04 version with 6.2 kernel, and bam, all the problems vanished into thin air. Nvidia's behaving perfectly now. I'd ticked the box for Third Party software during the Ubuntu install, so I didn't have to do diddly-squat after getting it up and running. As of today, I'm still not quite sure what it could have been. The CPU I'm using is from the 13th Intel generation, released just this year, so there might have also been some incompatibilities at play... Hopefully, this info helps out anyone else in the same boat.

This is my laptop configuration:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 13700H
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTC 1650 4GB
- SSD: 2TB Corsair Core XT
- OS: Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: A free Ubuntu Pro subscription in Ubuntu 22.04 would accomplish the same thing. I'm using Ubuntu Pro and Linux kernel 6.2.0-26 in Ubuntu 22.04.